# Ace-Editor Ignore/whitelist some tag/string

Tags: reactjs, ace-editor

Is there any way to avoid Ace-Editor to raise an error if I use some tag like <#input "asd">?? Like a whitelist to suggest AceEditor to ignore it... Anyway, It's an internal key and I cannot avoid using it.
I'm using react.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of two ways to solve the issue:

1) Maybe you can bind the ">", get the last entered values and then clear the errors:

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: "dotCommand1",
    bindKey: { win: ".", mac: "."},
    exec: function () {
        var pos = editor.selection.getCursor();
        var session = editor.session;

        var curLine = (session.getDocument().getLine(pos.row)).trim();
        var curTokens = curLine.slice(0, pos.column).split(/\s+/);

        //You can build a logic using the curTokens array and then when you find <#input "asd"> clear the errors.

        // If we assume curTokens[0] to have the value  

        if(curTokens[0] === '<#input "asd">') {
            editor.session.setAnnotations([]); // This would remove the being shown error
        }            
    }
});
```

2) Use the on change event and use the above similar logic and then clear the error

```
editor.getSession().on('change', function () {
    // same logic as above
})
```